# Migrating Azure SQL database to Azure sql Managed instance

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-managed-instance, azure-data-factory

What are different options to move database from "Azure sql server" to "Azure sql managed instance", Looks like below options are not possible
1) Azure migration service - Not supporting azure sql server as source 
2) bacpac and use sqlpackage to import, this is not working and getting struck with no result

only options i see is through Azure data factory with self hosted integration runtime

is there any better options to move from "Azure sql server" to "Azure managed instance"

Comment: Have you tried using the [GUI](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5189/restore-an-azure-sql-database-from-one-server-to-another-server/) to export a bacpac and import that into your managed instance? Does that give you any error details?

Answer (score 3):

The only way to go with this to get the bacpac file for your Azure SQL Database. Then import this bacpac file into your Managed Instance. This can be achieved through :

1. SSMS
2. Export\import using sqlpackage.exe
3. Via portal which appears to be a bit slow as the Azure SQL Database Import/Export service provides a limited number of compute virtual machines (VMs) per region to process import and export operations
4. SSDT
5. bcp

This link explains each method : [Export bacpac](https://sqlbackupandftp.com/blog/how-to-backup-azure-sql-database-to-local-machine)

Once done. Import the bacpac file into your managed instance using SSMS,sqlpackage or portal.

This will walk you through the process : [Import bacpac](https://www.sqlshack.com/import-sample-bacpac-file-azure-sql-database/)

Comment: I've automated this type of approach, works well. Performance depends on data volumes for larger (>Gb of data) but below that it's more driven by the time taken to transfer the schema